# "Cannot access secondary GPU" error on a Lenovo y580

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I've laptop with nvidia optimus technology. I'm trying to run the nvidia graphic card (ubuntu 12.10 32bit).

I did everything from this tutorial http://blog.urosevic.net/2012/10/13/2567/lenovo-ideapad-y580-nvidia-gtx-660m-ubuntu-12-04/ but still have error:

```
optirun -vv glxspheres
[ 1285.268398] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 1285.269054] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[ 1285.418607] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.0.1 starting...
[ 1285.418648] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 1285.418658] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 1285.418667] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 1285.418676] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
[ 1285.418685] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 1285.418694] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 1288.019770] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to assign any connected display devices to X screen 0

[ 1288.019790] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to assign any connected display devices to X screen 0

[ 1288.019799] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 1288.019807] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[ 1288.019811] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

Answer (score 2):

In file `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` I had to change

"ConnectedMonitor" to "UseDisplayDevice" AND "DFP" to "none".

This made this also works for a Lenovo Y480 GeForceGT 650M.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good guide [here](http://chrislaidler.blogspot.ru/2012/12/getting-nvidia-optimus-working-on-my.html) for installing the missing/broken parts of the bumblebee/optimus drivers just think of the yum lines as sudo apt-get install.

The bits you actually need is the git section and then change /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia "ConnectedMonitor" to "UseDisplayDevice" AND "DFP" to "none" as previously suggested and then optirun runs smoothly